# Case statement allow a where clause on the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing the following in a query as such

```
  case  WHEN PreAllocationDespatch IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE PreAllocationDespatch END AS 'Allocated'
  case  WHEN LineQuantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE LineQuantity END AS 'Ordered'
  case  WHEN LineQuantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE LineQuantity - PreAllocationDespatch   END AS 'Balance'
```

Which is fine and does what its meant to do but I need to be able to say

```
Where Balance != LineQuantity
```

to give me a list of products that have not been actioned yet. But cause it is a dynamic column I can't appear to do that. The columns in question are both ints.

> PreAllocationDespatch
>
> LineQuantity

Comment: That's a case _expression_ not a statement

Comment: Think again. If you need to test for nulls in PreAllocationDespatch and LineQuantity, then you also need to do the same for your computed value. And you overcomplicate things. Balance = LineQuantity only if PreAllocationDespatch is null or zero. So basically - just test for a non-zero value in PreAllocationDespatch.

Comment: And notice how others have assumed aggregation is involved. Post a complete sql statement so that guessing is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

for a resulting value   you could use having

```
having  Balance != LineQuantity
```

or repeat the case in where

```
where (case WHEN LineQuantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE LineQuantity - PreAllocationDespatch END )  != LineQuantity
```

Comment: Would having honor the case column though ?

Comment: @rogue39nin  the having clause work on result so should eval the  calcluated  result based on column alias

Comment: Having is not for calculated values, but for aggregated ones. `Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used with a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, there is an implicit single, aggregated group.` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a second simple second select with your where statement or use a having if your query allows it (we don't have the full query so we wouldn't know)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join to define the values.

However, it might be simpler to express the logic as:

```
where coalesce(LineQuantity, 0) <> PreAllocationDespatch
```